# Putting an equation inside a struct

Tags: swift, function, struct

Really new to coding but wondering if there was a way to put an equation as a func into a struct and have it solve based on an "if/else" statement.

Example

```
struct Person {
    var weight: Double
    var height: Double
    var male: Bool
    init(weight: Double, height: Double, gender: Bool) {
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.male = male
    }
    func BMI() -> Double {
        if self.male {
            return weight/height x height
        } else {
            return weight x height x height
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: There is no question here. What's the issue? Compiler error, logic error, etc? Or is it that you are using `x` for multiply instead of `*`?

Comment: Be aware that Swift (and most other programming languages) _are not_ capable of symbolic algebra operations (i.e. they are not [Computer Algebra Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system)) so you cannot direct Swift, or C, or C++, or C#, or Java, etc) to "solve" an equation - or perform any other kind of _reduction_ of an expression or system of expressions. Now, there _are_ CAS libraries for those languages, but (with limited exceptions) they don't "extend" the language or make CAS feel integrated - you'd just pass an algebraic expression in a `string`. Just FYI.